# Deployment failed with error in VSTS CD pipeline despite configs exist

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I am deploying my artifacts to Azure portal, I am getting following error.

```
Error: XML transformation error while transforming D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_22187855225775688\Content\D_C\a\1\s\MyApp.Web\obj\ReleaseWeb\Package\PackageTmp\Web.config using D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_22187855225775688\Content\D_C\a\1\s\MyApp.Web\obj\ReleaseWeb\Package\PackageTmp\Web.Testing.config.
```

while this file exist in my artifacts.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by permutation & combination with my transformations, it was the issue of transformations but error message mislead me. There was an issue in my Web.Testing.config file.

Comment: THank you Leo Liu

Answer (score 0):

your path in the error is `release` and in your explorer window its `releaseweb`

Comment: I have modified the question now.

Comment: still the path doesnt match, i dont really understand, another issue that might be, your transforms are invalid

Comment: I can't show the real name of my application so i used MyApp.Web.

Comment: its not only that, path is different either way

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but a slightly different cause - if you have a web.release.config file it will always be applied first. So if you then have web.environment2.config file and are deploying to a that through a stage called environment2 in Azure devops, it actually runs both transforms, first the release one then the stage one.

The problem with this is it tries to remove the debug attribute twice from system.web. The fix is to remove this line in web.environment2.config:

```
<system.web>
   <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />   <!-- REMOVE THIS!-->
```